# Displaying Across the Command Prompt

Tags: python, stdout

This is what I am trying to do, I am using the command prompt

```
import time

mess = list("StackOverflow")
def myFunc():
  for i in xrange(1000):
      for k in mess:
          print k
          time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myFunc()
```

I am trying to span the display across the cmd prompt, Basically try a matrix effect, how do i go about this..

Take a look at the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjspP.png

All I want to know is, if its possible to print vertically on all the columns at once, and then the chars dropping down(not horizontal)

Comment: "I am trying to span the display across the cmd prompt,"... What do you mean?

Comment: i mean the output shud cover the whole cmd prompt window... the above display on one line, i want the same thing to be repeated accross the window.

Comment: You dont need to do `list("text")`... A string is iterable in python. `for char in "Hello!": print(char)`. If you're trying to print multiple strings: `for strng in ("hello", "hi", "how are you"): print(strng)`.

Comment: And what's wrong with what you have now? Is it not working as expected? If so, what is wrong with it?

Comment: YEah actually i was trying my own, hence made a quick one.. m a newbee in Python
i.imgur.com/J4p58.png 
Consider them to falling vertically all at once...

Comment: Can I ask what the point of this program is? Seems pretty useless IMHO, not trying to be mean.

Comment: :D yeah pretty useless... Maybe..but just came across my mind if something can be done to make a matrix effect with print statements.. actually, this ud let me know if i can start printing on the columns all at once... If thats not possible with Python :( m sorry to ask the question then..

Comment: @Whiskey: I would check out the curses module for python.

Comment: I have edited the post, and gave a screenshot, for clarification of my question. I want them to be dropping down vertically

Comment: @JoelCornett Thanks i will check that..

Comment: @JoelCornett Seems Curses module dsnt work on windows.. i get an import error, and when i looked for it... i found it dsnt support windows.

>>> import curses

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    import curses
  File "D:\Python27\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ImportError: No module named _curses
>>>

Comment: @Whiskey: Yeah I should have mentioned that. I think you may be SOL. Alternatively, you could try using a GUI package (like Tkinter, or WxPython) to _emulate_ a console window... although at that point it may be getting a little ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

[By default, `print` includes a newline](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement).
You can specify that it not do so by adding a comma to the end of the `print` statement.

And then, at least on my system, you run into the problem of buffered output.
So I included a call to flush stdout.

```
import sys, time

mess = "StackOverflow"
def myFunc():
  for i in xrange(1000):
      for k in mess:
          print k,
          sys.stdout.flush()
          time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myFunc()
```

---

Equivalent code for Python 3:

```
import sys, time

mess = "StackOverflow"
def myFunc():
  for i in range(1000):
      for k in mess:
          print(k, end=" ")
          sys.stdout.flush()
          time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myFunc()
```

Comment: I am sorry i think m not able to explain clearly....

I want a matrix effect to be created with the string passed... the string is "Stackoverflow", i want
s s s s s 
t t t t t
a t t t t
c c c c c 
k k k k k 
o o o o o
.........

and so on.. all at the same time dropping down..accross the window

Comment: Please take a look at this.. http://i.imgur.com/J4p58.png I want the chars to fall down vertically from top to bottom.. all at once...

Comment: OK. Thank you for the clarification. The code I posted produces the expected output. However it does not do so in the order you specify. I am not aware of anything that produces output in such an order.

Comment: Thanks bernie... for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If all you want is to print it out like that, then simply do this:

```
import sys

strng = "S t a c k O v e r f l o w"
for i in range(10000):
    sys.stdout.write(strng)
```

Have you tried simply doing this?

```
import time, sys

stackOverflow = "stackoverflow"

for i in range(10000):
    for char in stackOverflow:
        for j in range(3):
            sys.stdout.write(char + " ")
            time.sleep(0.1)

    print("") #Newline
```